# mysql: avoid writing outfile if no records are found

Tags: mysql

I use a query like this to write into a csv file:

```
select 'column_name1', 'column_name2', 'column_name3' union all select column1, column2, column3 from mytable where id = 123 into outfile '/my/path/file.csv';
```

Is it possible to avoid writing to the file when the second part of the union statement does not find any records? (In other words if the number of total rows is 1.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) as follows:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `my_function`;

CREATE DEFINER = `user`@`%` FUNCTION `my_function`() RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE id = 123 LIMIT 1 INTO @records;
  IF @records > 0 THEN
    SELECT 'column_name1', 'column_name2', 'column_name3' 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM mytable WHERE id = 123
    INTO OUTFILE '/my/path/file.csv';
  END IF;
  RETURN 0;
END
```